Flutter build windows app not run when move it to different directory
My flutter windows build application run normally after i build it, but when i copy the build directory to another folder it doesn't run.
i think it because something is wrong with the serius_python plugin, because it happend only after i add it to my code.
here the code:
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  speechToText();

  // runApp(const LoginPageAdmin());
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Progress()),
      ],
      child: const LoginPageAdmin(),
    ),
  );
}

Future<void> speechToText() async {
  await SeriousPython.runProgram(
    "D:/D/demofastapi/main.pyc",
    sync: false,
  );
}


Please help!!!!
I just want it to run

seems main.pyc has been recolated, can you try with msix
